# Trying to make add Autorole to my bot but get TypeError: fn.bind is not a function

Tags: discord.js

I'm new to coding javascript and I'm coding discord.js. I've been trying to add an auto role feature so that when someone joins the discord server they automatically obtain the default role. However, I've been struggling as all the tutorials or other code explaining it is usually out-dated. So when I try and run the bot I get this error message.

```
TypeError: fn.bind is not a function
  at Map.find (C:\Users\stuar\Desktop\Discord Bot\node modulesN^discordjs\collection\dist\index.js:158:21) at Client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\stuar\Desktop\Discord Bot\index.js:71:41)
  at Client.emit (events.js:327:22)
  at Object.module.exports [as GUILD_MEMBER_ADD] (C:\Users\stuar\Desktop\Discord Bot\node modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\GUILD MEMBER ADD.js:16:14)
  at WebSocketManager. handlePacket (C : \Users\stuar\Desktop\Discord Bot \node_modules\discordjs\src\client \websocket \WebSocketManager. j s : 386:31 )
  at WebSocketShard.onPacket (C:\Users\stuar\Desktop\Discord Bot\node modules\discord.j s\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:436:22)
  at WebSocketShard.onMessage (C:\Users\stuar\Desktop\Discord Bot\node modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js: 293:10)
  at WebSocket.onMessage (C:\Users\stuar\Desktop\Discord Bot\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:125:16)
  at WebSocket.emit (events.js:315:29)
  at Receiver.receiverOnMessage (C:\Users\stuar\Desktop\Discord Bot\node_modules\ws\lib\websocket.js: 800:20)
```

And this is my code that it seems to not like:

```js
// Auto Role
client.on('guildMemberAdd", member => {
  console.log("User " + member.user.tag + " has joined the server!");
  var role = member.guild.roles.cache.find("name", "User");
  member.addRole(role);
});
```

Comment: That happens when your node.js is not up to date, you should update node

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow! When you post a question, please avoid using images instead of copying the code using the proper formatting. For this question I've done it for you so that you can see how to do that, but don't post images in the future or your question can get flagged and closed. For more info, please see [ask]

Answer (score 1):

You're using an old version of `Collection.find()`: in its current version the "property-value" way of using `.find` is no longer supported, you need to provide a function. You can find the docs [here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection?scrollTo=find).
Here's how you can code it:

```js
client.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {
  let role = member.guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.name == 'User')
  member.roles.add(role)
})
```

Also, as you may have noticed, you also need to write `member.roles.add`, since [`GuildMember.addRole()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMemberRoleManager?scrollTo=add) is a method from v11.

Comment: Thanks you, I've struggled as all the things I've been reading are outdaded and for odler versions

Comment: No worries :) If this answer solved your problem, please accept it: this wat the question will be marked as answered and everybody will know that the problem is solved